# VS code syntax highlighting for GitHub Actions is broken (for me)

Tags: visual-studio-code, yaml, github-actions

I use VS code.  I am starting a new project that is using GitHub Actions.  I am using Red Hat's [YAML](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-yaml) extension.

It usually works great.  It *says* that is has support for GitHub Workflows and GitHub Actions. But it is very "confused" regarding what should be highlighted.  The code in the screenshot below works - I have deployed successfully - and it is messing up very obvious highlighting. In the screenshot, I am hovering over elements in the `env` list and you can see that it is saying that environment variables must be booleans.  (FWIW, I also tried putting in a boolean and then it complained about it not being a key-value pair, which is actually correct.)

[image: VS Code Screen Capture: Incorrect Syntax Highlighting]

It appears that [others are also having this problem](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-yaml/issues/397) and there was a [suggestion given here](https://github.com/redhat-developer/vscode-yaml/issues/397#issuecomment-896049900) that should have fixed it but didn't.

Has anyone else had trouble setting up GitHub Actions syntax highlighting?